# Series representation of Riemann zeta function in denominator

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta, divergent-series

**Are there known any series that converge for $\Re(s)>0$ or at least for $\Re(s)>\frac{1}{2}$ that are equal to $\frac{f(s)}{\zeta (s)}$, where $\zeta (s)$ is Riemann zeta function and $f(s)$ is arbitrary function?**

Examples that I already know:
$$\tag{1}\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\mu (n)}{n^s}=\frac{1}{\zeta (s)}$$
$$\tag{2}\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\lambda (n)}{n^s}=\frac{\zeta (2 s)}{\zeta (s)}$$
$$\tag{3}\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\phi (n)}{n^s}=\frac{\zeta (s-1)}{\zeta (s)}$$
where $\mu (n)$ is Möbius function, $\lambda (n)$ is Liouville function and $\phi (n)$ is Euler's totient function.

$(1)$ and $(2)$ seem to converge for $\Re(s)>\frac{1}{2}$ but proof of it is still an open problem, as far as I know. $(3)$ converge only for $\Re(s)>2$.

I mean there are plenty representations of $\zeta (s)$ in numerator as series that converge in whole critical strip but I can not find any for $\zeta (s)$ in denominator.
**Do you know any other examples of such series?**

EDIT: Of course I meant to converge in critical strip except poles caused by nontrivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$.

Comment: Seems unlikely: a nice series that that will probably give you RH.

Comment: There are other examples - see my [lecture notes](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_27_analytic_nt_course.pdf), page 96, or page 98.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde Nice examples, but all seems to converge only outside critical strip.

Comment: Do you understand that $\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$ has infinitely many poles in the critical strip ? Thus the answer to your question is : no if RH is false, $f(s)$ isn't built on $\zeta(s)$, and the series has to converge locally uniformly (which is the case for Dirichlet series in their half-plane of convergence). RH is true **iff** (1),(2) converge for $\Re(s) > 1/2$, the proof is very similar to the prime number theorem.

Comment: @reuns So to have series that converge in whole critical strip except the poles is impossible? Or except whole line $\Re(s)=1/2$?

Comment: No.  Search about abscissa of convergence of Dirichlet series. (1),(2) converge for $\Re(s)  > \sigma_0$ where $\sigma_0 = \sup_{\rho, \zeta(\rho) = 0} \Re(\rho)$. We don't know if $\sigma_0 < 1$. The RH is $\sigma_0 = 1/2$.

Comment: @reuns I understand that proving or disproving of convergence of $(1)$ in $\Re(s)>1/2$ proves or disproves RH. But I do ask for series with proved region of convergence. **Series with numerical evidence of convergence in any portion of critical strip will suffice.** And examples $(1)$ and $(2)$ are such cases. Do you know any other? (say also for region $0<\Re(s)<1/2$)?

Comment: The most important one is $\frac{-\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}-\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (\Lambda(n)-1) n^{-s}$. Of course you can create many other such series. Proving "(1) converges for $\Re(s) > 1/2$ $\implies$ RH" is easy. Proving "RH $\implies$ (1) converges for $\Re(s) > 1/2$" is as hard as proving the prime number theorem.

Comment: @reuns Series $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\Lambda (n)}{n^s}=-\frac{\zeta ' s}{\zeta (s)}$ were also in my mind when writting the question, but then I forgot to write them. But it also converges only outside critical strip.

Comment: $\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}$ has a pole at $s=1$, that's all the point of the PNT